# Reverse the order of Filter Function Output

Tags: google-sheets

I have a filter function providing me a list of items. I need to get that list in reverse order.

Here is the formula I'm using.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(T15:T&"Q "&U15:U,S15:S=TRUE))
```

Here is the Data it is filtering:

```
ColS    ColT   ColU
TRUE    3      2022
TRUE    3      2022
TRUE    4      2022
FALSE   4      2022
TRUE    4      2022
TRUE    1      2023
FALSE   1      2023
TRUE    1      2023
FALSE   2      2023
TRUE    2      2023
TRUE    2      2023
FALSE   3      2023
FALSE   3      2023
FALSE   3      2023
FALSE   4      2023
FALSE   4      2023
FALSE   4      2023
```

And here is the output:

```
3Q 2022
4Q 2022
1Q 2023
2Q 2023
```

The desired output is the reverse order or:

```
2Q 2023
1Q 2023
4Q 2022
3Q 2022
```

Is there anyway to do this in one formula without having to create another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(B2:C,A2:A=TRUE),2,0,1,0)),INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(x,1) &"Q "& CHOOSECOLS(x,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. This did the trick. I managed to actually find another way to do it but I will select this as the answer and then post my own answer for others that may be curious of another method. If you don't mind, could you explain how this works in your post?

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Solution:

You can alternatively use this `custom formula` I have created using Apps Script as a solution to your problem. The custom formula behaves like a google sheet formula with the required parameter.

### Custom Formula:

```
=uniqueValues(range)
```

range = the data range you want to select

> Please note that the range selection must have the same data format
> from your given example above

### Script:

```
function uniqueValues(range) {
  var data = range;
  var trueValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === true) {
      var quarter = data[i][1] + "Q";
      var year = data[i][2];
      var key = quarter + " " + year;
      trueValues.push(key)
    }
  };
  var uniqueArray = [...new Set(trueValues)];
  var finalValue = uniqueArray.reverse();
  return finalValue
}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: While I like this solution, I was hoping to not have to use scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted Harun24hr's response as the official answer but I did find another method to achieve this using the following formula.

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(S15:U,"SELECT T,U WHERE S=true ORDER by U DESC,T DESC")),,COLUMNS(QUERY(S15:U,"SELECT T,U WHERE S=true ORDER by U DESC,T DESC")))))," ","Q ")))
```

For those of you that are more experienced, let me know if this is a better option than Harun24hr's formula or not and why if you can. Is one less taxing than the other? I can't tell.

Comment: One drawback I see to this is that if columns are changed (removed, added) the query statement does not change. It has to be manually changed. Another plus for Harun24hr's answer.